# Unable to read text with Times new roman font using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, itext

When I read text with times new roman font I am getting unicode characters like '\u0010\u0014.But I am able to read Arial font successfully.I am using iTextSharp for my pdf automation test.I think itextsharp is not supporting times new roman.Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: It's not as trivial as you assume. iText supports text extraction for PDFs that contain the information as required by the text extraction algorithm from the PDF specification. Some PDFs don't contain that information, either not at all or only in faked/incorrect form. This may be a missing feature or bug of the PDF generator. Or it may be by design to prevent text extraction. If you shared an example PDF for which you observe the issue, we could analyze it and at least try to guess which is the case here.

Comment: Can you extract text with Acrobat? Just copy/paste will do, If you can't nobody can.